# Full width rows and surrounding container

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the latest version of Zurb Foundation. I'm wanting to use full width layout and make use of the off canvas element.

So I have a [demo](http://ryanmcdonough.co.uk/labs/foundation/layout/index.html) highlighting the issue, however I want full width rows but still be able to surround that row with a full width background colour. (E.g http://foundation.zurb.com/) like the hero block.

For simplicity this is the code in question:

HTML

```
 <section class="content-block">
      <div class="row full-page">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
              <h3>We&rsquo;re stoked you want to try Foundation! </h3>
              <p>To get going, this file (index.html) includes some basic styles you can modify, play around with, or totally destroy to get going.</p>
              <p>Once you've exhausted the fun in this document, you should check out:</p>             
          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.full-page {
   min-width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
}


.content-block {
    background:#000;
}
```

I would expect that the full width of the page would be black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on the `.columns` elements they use float. This make the element out of the flow, thus does not size on it's content anymore(because the content isn't in the same flow and just overflows).

To force the element to stay in the same flow, you can use:

```
.full-page {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: initial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/994L2/2)

Comment: @RyanMcDonough I found the real problem why this happens. And it seems you want to force the element on your `.full-page` element. Check my update!

Comment: perfect thanks! yeah I noticed it wasn't getting a height or anything, I tried to set a min height but that just set the bar to that height and somewhere randomly on the page.